# "My goal is to be happy" or "being happy" - Which of them is correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of these is grammatical?

> My goal is to be happy.

or

> My goal is being happy.

My friend told me that the second one is incorrect, but I don't believe my friend about this.

Comment: What is the doubt that you have?

Comment: about employing them...

Comment: "Which of them is correct, and why?"

Comment: OK. Why do you think either one is or isn't correct?

Comment: Because a friend told me that the last one is incorrect

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your friend an English native speaker?

Comment: The first, "to be" is an infinitive. The second, "being" is a gerund. Both function equally well in the sentence.

Comment: "Being happy is my goal", is more idiomatic.  But there is nothing grammatically wrong at all.  It is mildly surprising to have maintaining-a-state, rather than attaining-a-state as a goal but nothing in grammar says you can't.